# C# CompactFramework Dynamically access SOAP Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, compact-framework

I am trying to create a small application for Windows CE devices running on a scanner that supports the .Net CompactFramework 3.5.
The problem I have is, that I have to connect to a webservice with several IP-Addresses. On default .Net Framework I can change the property URL-Behaviour of the WebReference created with wsdl.exe to "Dynamic" and then I should be able to reference to an IP-Address defined in an config file.
But not so in CompactFramework.
I have changed the property already to dynamic an modified the constructor of the WebReference to the following:

```
public partial class WS_SCAN_WSDL : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
    public WS_SCAN_WSDL(String ls_webserviceLocation) {
        this.Url = ls_webserviceLocation+"/WS_SCAN_WSDL";
    }

    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://192.1.2.4:8085/MYSCAN/WS_SCAN/SearchItems", RequestNamespace = "http://192.1.2.4:8085/MYSCAN/WS_SCAN", ResponseNamespace = "http://192.1.2.4:8085/MYSCAN/WS_SCAN", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public System.Data.DataSet SearchItems([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] string iXMLString, out int sqlcode) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("SearchItems", new object[] {
                    iXMLString});
        sqlcode = ((int)(results[1]));
        return ((System.Data.DataSet)(results[0]));
    }
    [...]
}
```

Now when calling the webservice like:

```
WS_SCAN_WSDL lsrv_myService = new WS_SCAN_WSDL("http://192.1.2.4:8085/MYSCAN");
```

everything works fine. If I will call it like:

```
WS_SCAN_WSDL lsrv_myService = new WS_SCAN_WSDL("http://194.3.1.6:8082/MYSCAN");
```

Nothing will work. The WebService is avaiable on both Locations but the second calling will raise an WebException and I cannot proceed.

Is there any possibility to create a dynamical WebService Proxy for .Net CompactFramework?

//Edit:
Maybe I have localized the main problem, but I am not sure if so.
The Webservice description says the following:

```
<definitions name="MY_SCAN_WSDL" targetNamespace="http://192.1.2.4:8085/MYSCAN">
    <types>
    [...]
```

and the other Webservice-description says:

```
<definitions name="MY_SCAN_WSDL" targetNamespace="http://194.3.1.6:8082/MYSCAN">
    <types>
    [...]
```

Is it possible that the problem caused on the different namespaces? Is it possible that both webservices will have the same namespace on different IPs? Or is it possible to change this during runtime?

Comment: I'm swamped with work, but have you seen this? [Calling WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164240.aspx) You need to have the **new** *NetCFSvcUtil* to make it work. Download that from [HERE](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/0/6205ED05-E435-44FC-AA82-B763CA5F8B1A/NetCFSvcUtil.exe).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, that the namespace may never be equal so the server that holds the webservice allows me to set up an namespace e.g. `http://myuri.org` but the server will always add the databasealias to namespace so the namespace may be `http://myuri.org/DB123` and on next device it may be `http://myuri.org/DB_321`. I solved the problem on creating the request manually with configuration defined namespaces and servers. Thanks!